# My Chinese characters change to question marks in an email

Tags: java, email, utf-8, character-encoding

I retrieve a value from a DB field which looks like two boxes [][] in the sql/developer.
When I copy and paste that value to outlook (new message window) and send it to myself I can see the correct Chinese characters in the email 测试.

However If I do that via java code, meaning retrieve the value from db and send the email from java I get two ?? question marks in the resulting email in outlook.

The original setting in java code was:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
```

I also tried to send the email with these settings:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Nothing helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set your connection encoding to be utf-8

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it in your control panel

Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options